# Interrupting UIScrollView Bounce after it has started?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I have a UIWebView that loads a new request when the user scrolls a set distance past the end, or before the beginning of the content (ie. into the area that "bounces" back), via the scrollView delegate

Unfortunately, I have found that once the bounce animation starts, it has to complete, and completely bounce back to the edge of the content area, before the UIWebView will display the new content that it has loaded.

Is there any way to interrupt this, and have it not need to bounce back before displaying the new content? I would prefer for the old content just to disappear without needing to bounce all the way back to its edge . Either that, or speed up the animation.

Things to note:

- I do NOT want to turn off bouncing.
- I have tried importing quartzcore and using -removeAllAnimations on every view I can think of, including the superview, and it doesn't help.
- I have tested it, and it is not because of latency in the loading of the request that is causing the delay in displaying the new content.
- There are a few UIViewAnimationOptions  that look like they could be helpful, but I can't see where I would use them, and I don't really want to subclass UIWebview if I can help it.

Any ideas?

- thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried simply setting the `contentOffset` of the scroll view at the point when you want it to stop?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. It doesn't seem to do anything once the bounce animation has started. I'm pretty sure that with animations, whatever you are animating towards is actually set at the beginning of the animation. Meaning (for example), if you are animating towards an alpha of 0.0, then the official alpha is 0.0 right from the beginning of the animation, so if you test for this before the animation has finished it will still report that the alpha is 0.0. So with my problem, it already thinks the offset is what I want it to be, even though it doesn't appear that way. (hope that makes sense)

Comment: My problem is that this kicks off the loading of a number of web views on the page. All the other ones load almost immediately, and only the one that the user has interacted with loads slowly (after the bounce animation). I'm beginning to think I might just give up and use a different method to call the new requests, rather than checking for an offset out side of the bounds.